# How to use mutate on list?

Tags: r, dplyr

What is the correct way to mutate a list? In this specific case the list is being returned by `split`

```
library(dplyr)
csv<-data.frame(participant_number=c(1,1,1,2,2),SelfEsteem=c(3,4,2,1,3))
csv<-csv%>%split(.,.$participant_number)%>%mutate(.,var(.$SelfEsteem))
```

Error:

```
Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "list"
```

**UPDATE In answer to comments**: I intend to calculate the variance of `SelfEsteem` each group (the grouping var is `participant_number`). If I try `group_by` I do not get the expected result....Why?

```
library(dplyr)

#Please note I changed the dataframe to make my point about variance differences more obvious
csv<-data.frame(participant_number=c(1,1,1,2,2),SelfEsteem=c(3,4,2,1,3))

csv<-csv%>%group_by(participant_number)%>%mutate(.,SE_variance=var(.$SelfEsteem))

#var(c(3,4,2)) #1
#var(c(1,3))  #2
```

Expected:

```
        participant_number SelfEsteem SE_variance
(dbl)            (dbl)       (dbl)
1                  1          3         1
2                  1          4         1
3                  1          2         1
4                  2          1         2
5                  2          3         2
```

Comment: The `d` in `dplyr` is for data frames. If you want to mutate each data frame in a list you do it the same way you'd do anything else to each data frame in a list `lapply`, a for loop, or `purrr` package.

Comment: Though from your example, why are you bothering to `split`? Just `group_by` instead and keep it as one data frame.

Comment: Do you intend to apply different mutate for each list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your attempt with `group_by` fails because you override `mutate`'s search path. Mutate uses non-standard evaluation, so it will look for variables first among the columns of it's `data` argument.

When you use pipes (`%>%`), a dot `.` refers to *the whole data frame*, and `.$SelfEsteem` refers to the *whole* SelfEsteem column from the *whole* data frame.

You just need to simplify a little bit (not override the defaults) to get the expected result.

```
csv %>% 
  group_by(participant_number) %>%
  mutate(SE_variance = var(SelfEsteem))
# Source: local data frame [5 x 3]
# Groups: participant_number [2]
# 
#   participant_number SelfEsteem SE_variance
#                (dbl)      (dbl)       (dbl)
# 1                  1          3           1
# 2                  1          4           1
# 3                  1          2           1
# 4                  2          1           2
# 5                  2          3           2
```

Answer (score 3):

If you really need to use a `list` object, you can `mutate` a `list` using `map` from the purrr library:

```
library(dplyr) 
library(purrr) 

csv %>% 
    split(.,.$participant_number) # your list 
    map(~mutate(.,var(.$SelfEsteem))) # this will mutate a list
```

Now, you can put everything back together with `bind_rows()`

```
csv %>% 
  split(.,.$participant_number) %>% 
  map(~mutate(.,var(.$SelfEsteem))) %>% 
  bind_rows()
```

and you get what you need.