# Arithmetic operations on R lists

Tags: r, list, date-arithmetic, arithmetic-expressions

I have a `data.frame` with variables of data type `list` and whose values are in `Date` format. How do I calculate the difference between two dates coming from 2 different variables and name it `YrsEmployed` and data type `list` as well?

Please note that `StartHireDate` and `EndHireDate` below are `Date` formatted. I just don't know how to display them as `Date`

```
> > print(HiringDateInfo)
          X_id                                                     StartHireDate
1 530eed6dbfb5c1a8e77cb0fc                            NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
2 5391a88bbfb5c1b1fed0bcf4                            NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
3 53a0fa3cf1f17922a0287add                            NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
4 53abd15cf1f179c3e81a3fbe                            NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
5 54dd934ff1f179acfb7b0a2f 14304, 15095, 15279, 15431, 15492, 15645, 15859, NA, 16222, 16375
                                                        EndHireDate
1                            NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
2                            NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
3                            NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
4                            NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
5 15063, 15308, 15338, 15490, 15613, 15855, 16116, 16159, 16312, NA
```

I expect a new `data.frame` together with `YrsEmployed`

```
YrsEmployed
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
2.07945205479452,0.583561643835616,0.161643835616438,0.161643835616438,0.3315068,49315069,0.575342465753425,0.704109589041096,NA,0.246575342465753,NA
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not computing a new df for a single variable like YrsEmployed.
By loading the dplyr package you can mutate the new column YrsEmployed.
First you change the columns into dates with this code:

```
HiringDateInfo$StartHireDate <- as.Date(HiringDateInfo$StartHireDate, format = "depending on your formate")
HiringDateInfo$EndHireDate <- as.Date(HiringDateInfo$EndHireDate, format = "depending on your formate")
```

After that, you can compute the YrsEmployed with the mutate function form dplyr.
Hope it works!

Comment: I appreciate your answer. I am tidying my data and on the process of creating the variables that are really necessary and crucial for further analysis. One of the variables needed to be created is the YrsEmployed. That is why I need it in my new df. Is there a way I could do that?

Comment: `newdf <- HiringDateInfo %>% mutate(YrsEmployed = Start - End) %>% select(YrsEmployed)`

Comment: thank you but I got this error: Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: non-numeric argument to binary operator.

Comment: my data types for the StartDate and EndDate are both list and I expect the YrsEmployed should also be with data type list.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: [how to mutate on list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37975872/how-to-use-mutate-on-list). The result should be data type list.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did to get around it. 
1. I define a function `function(x, y) list(((x-y)/365)*1)`
2. Then use `mapply` to come with the desired new variable `mapply(fdiff, HiringDateInfo$EndHireDate, HiringDateInfo$StartHireDate)`